# Module over skew polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, polynomial-rings

Let $\sigma$ be an endomorphism of a skew field $D$ and consider the skew polynomial ring $$R= D[X,\sigma]$$

which is a ring of left polynomials $\sum_{i} a_i X^i$ with twisted multiplication given by

$$Xa = \sigma(a) X$$

Consider the $R$-quotient module

$$M_d:= R/R(X-d)$$

Note that $D$ is an $R$-module via the action $$Xr= \sigma(r) d, r \in D$$

I'm trying to show that

$$D \cong M_d$$ as $R$-modules (it will then follow that $M_d$ is simple).

I defined the map

$$\psi: R\to D: f \mapsto f(d)$$

and want to apply the isomorphism theorem on this map. But I have trouble showing this map is $R$-linear. I can see it suffices to show that

$$\psi(Xf) = X\psi(f)$$

but when I calculate this with a generic element they are not equal?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you should not be sending $X^n$ to $d^n$ but rather to
$$\sigma^{n-1}(d)\cdots \sigma(d)d.$$

For instance, with your definition $\psi(X^2)$ is sent to $d^2$ but $X\psi(X)$ is sent to $X\cdot d = \sigma(d)d$.

Comment: Where do I claim that $X^n$ gets sent to $d^n$? In the definition of the map $\psi$?

Comment: Well, how do you interpret $f(d)$ when $f= X^n$?

Comment: Ya, I think so. That's wrong then?

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer to make it clearer where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: Note that I'm still not convinced that the kernel of $\psi$ is $R(X-d)$, so maybe $M_d\simeq D$ is false. But at least the morphism $M_d\to D$ is well-defined now.

Comment: I did not get to that point as well. If you want a reference, this is in Lam's book "A first course in noncommutative rings", p188. In fact, they do not claim that $M_d \cong D$ but just that $M_d$ is simple. My professor argued that this followed from $M_d \cong D$ though.

Comment: In Lam they do identify $M_d$ and $D$ so they should be isomorphic.

Comment: I think the kernel is $R(X-d)$ for the following reason. $R$ has an Euclidean division on "left polynomials", so every non-zero left ideal is generated by any non-zero element of minimal degree. Clearly the kernel contains $X-d$ and thus this must generate the kernel, by minimality of degree (the kernel does not contain constants because otherwise this would be the zero map). Does this sound correct?